# Adding GridView for TabAcitivty fragments

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to add gridview for my layout.
The MainActivity contains 5 number of tabs , where first tab is AlbumsActivity.

AlbumsActivity

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends Fragment{
    public AlbumsActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_albums, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

I am using this class adapter to populate the grids in AlbumsActivity.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.splas,
            R.drawable.abc,       
    };


    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

grid_layout.xml

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

activity_albums.xml

This is layout file for AlbumsActivity , where i want to show grids in page.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.musiclist.AlbumsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ald"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong.

1. MainActivity - 5 Tabs and one framelayout
2. AlbumsActivity (Fragment) - Activity_Albums.xml (TextView, GridView)
3. ImageAdapter (BaseAdapter) - Custom Layout (ImageView)

> 3 -> 2 (Gridview) -> 1

if not you have to create, set parameters and inject gridview with custom layout to main layout programatically

//Try this

> activity_albums.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.musiclist.AlbumsActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ald"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

> AlbumsActivity

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends Fragment{
private View view;
private FrameLayout fl;
private GridView gv;
public AlbumsActivity() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_albums,container,false);
    fl = view.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    gv = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);    
    gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    fl.addView(gv);    
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       


}
```

}

Or Something similar, I am too lazy to type everything now. just google search "android custom arrayadapter" and you will find tons of examples. It's really simple

Comment: I want to add gridview for only first activity . I'm not trying to add it once.

Comment: The easiest way is use FrameLayout and replace it with gridview oncreate. If you don't want it in the future. you can simply hide that frame from view

Comment: Can you please show that edit in code. I'm not able to fix it.